# Skipping unnecessary xml nodes in jibx mapping

Tags: xml-parsing, jibx

I have a third party xml with me, which has many xml nodes that my application does not need to bother about. How skip such xml portions when binding with jibx.

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Praveen,
The easiest way to create a JiBX binding for a subset of a schema definition is to modify the schema definition to your desired schema.
This can be done easily and cleanly by running an xml transformation on the original schema to create your new simpler schema.
Take a look at this example of a maven project that modifies a schema before running JiBX:
https://github.com/jibx/schema-library/blob/master/net.webservicex/net.webservicex.currencyconvertor/pom.xml
I hope this helps.
Don